# Get reference to view in Universal App

Tags: caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn Micro beta in a universal application. I try to get access to a control on my page in OnViewLoaded method. However I get an exception that the control is inaccessible due to its protection level. I dont see anything in XAML where I have specified the control to be protected. Dont know how to fix it. Any ideas? I am using following code-

```
     protected override void OnViewLoaded(object view)
    {
        base.OnViewLoaded(view);
        MyView myView = view as MyView;
        if (MyView != null)
        {
            TextBlock tb=MyView.MyTextBlock;
        }

    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?  What you did there is bring a view into the viewmodel not necessarily a good thing in the MVVM world. What are you trying to do with the TextBlock?

Comment: Well...the textblock is only for asking question about. In my code I am using some propritery controls which have certain methods on them and hence have to use them in VM.

Comment: You won't be able to get access to the control itself from the view model. Would it make more sense to have in the code behind of the view?

Comment: But this code worked fine in WPF-this is the Caliburn recommended way of getting access to view in VMs. Has the approach changed for universal apps?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this worked in WPF is that the generated code for the xaml creates the control references as `internal` where in Windows 10 they're generated as `private`.

However as the above comments suggest this typically isn't an approach you'd want to do in an MVVM style application.

One approach is to create an interface `ICustomerView` (for instance) that the view implements. The methods on this view interface interact with the controls directly (and can because it's the accessing private control references).

In `OnViewLoaded` you can then cast the view to the interface and hold a reference to that.

This allows you to still interact with the view albeit through an interface which decouples the view from the view model and would still allow unit testing.

**Edit:** You can see an example in [this repository](https://github.com/nigel-sampson/xbox-media-remote/tree/master/XboxMediaRemote.App/Views) where the views are inheriting from `ViewBase` that implements `IView` which exposes a method for changing visual states.